# Where do I find the sofware Omnis after downloading

Tags: software-recommendation

I went to Omnis site and clicked Omnis Downloads (Linux).
Download the latest Omnis Studio Products, Installers, Patches and Component Updates. After 119MB download there is nothing about Omnis in the HUD or icon bar at left. Where do I find it to run the software? I use Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: what did the download resulted in? a tar.gz file?

Comment: Did you checked in `~/Downloads`?

Answer (score 0):

Any thing that you download, by default will reside in the Downloads folder.  You can click on files from dash, and once opened, click on Downloads.

[image]

Or, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cd Downloads/
```

[image]